# Function of と in the following sentence

Tags: particle-と

Is the function of と in this sentence kind of like the "if" と where there is an initial condition, that is followed by resulting condition?

この手紙から察すると彼は立腹してるようだ。

For example, "I gathered from the letter" RESULT -> "He seems angry"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

___から察すると means "judging from ___".

Here __と can be analyzed to mean **"if __"** or **"when __"** (source: Makino & Tsutsui, Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar p. 480); i.e., the sentence could be literally translated as "If one judges from" or "When one judges from".

A similar use of __と would be
無用なものを入れると、無用なものしか取り出せない。
*If you put useless stuff in, you can only get useless stuff out*.